# concatenar en vba para enviar por correo

Tags: php, vba, outlook

Estoy usando la funcion ShellExecute que me permite abri un link desde una macro en outlook,necesito poder leer el correo y mandar la informacion a traves de un link donde un servidor en php la va procesar
¿Como concateno la x que tiene el nombre de pedro para poder enviarla en mi link?

```
x = "pedro"
 lSuccess = ShellExecute(0, "Open", "http://localhost/caet/formu.php?nombre=jose&email=correo")
```

Necesito que en mi php llamado formu llegue la variable pedro
Mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

La concatenacion en VBA es sencilla

```
texto_concatenado = "una cadena string" & x
```

En vba solo utilizas el simbolo '&' para unir, recordando que los textos que tu defines van entre comillas y las variables no.